# Loop Through Object Creation VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, loops

I have an array of strings with 12 strings containing the names of 12 notes of music from A to G#. Then I have a Class 'Scale' which have 8 properties. I want to create Objects of Class Scale by looping through the Array and using the strings in Array as the objects names. Can it be Done and if yes, How?

Answer (score 1):

Here's my initial answer. It can be modified as you provide more information, or maybe it's enough for you. Let me know.

It uses a `For Each` loop to iterate over each string in the notes array, then create new scales with those strings as their names. It creates 3 scales because there are 3 notes in my array.

```
Dim notes = {"A", "B", "C"}
Dim scales As New List(Of Scale)()
For Each note As String In notes
    Dim s As New Scale
    s.Name = note
    scales.Add(s)
Next
```

Comment: Let Me Try that, I will let you know, I was using a For Each loop but i didn't use the 'Name' Method. Thanks Anyway. :)

Comment: Verdino I tried that but couldn't find any method 'Name'. So I left the idea of naming the objects as Scale names and just added a traditional property which stores Scales Names. Now I am able to get the scale name from that property.

Comment: In the future it would be useful if you pasted some code examples in your original question. Without that, your question is open to interpretation.

Comment: Well i didnt have any code, i asked for suggestions about the code. :)

Comment: You don't have code but you have an idea of how it should be written, so why don't you write it like that? Then paste that code if you have trouble. That's how this site usually works. FYI for the future, if you paste a question like this without code, the community will usually down-vote it.

Comment: I didn't know the syntax as you don't know it. So i did something different to get the scale name. Your answer was incorrect.

Comment: It can't be correct without seeing your code. Without providing code, you will get answers which don't exactly work in your system and you will need to edit them. Don't expect us to read your mind.